# C# tableAdapter.Update() won't change the database record

Tags: database, tableadapter

I want my program to be able to change one row in my Access database with the data from my form.

The problem is that the update-function doesn't do anything.
There are no error messages and the program compiles correct. Nothing changes in the database.

Here is the code:

```
private void btnTallenna_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] vanhat = new string[9];
    lueVanhatTiedot(vanhat);

    hevosetTableAdapter.Connection.Close();
    hevosetTableAdapter.Connection.Open();
    try
    {
        hevosetTableAdapter.Update(txtNimi.Text, txtIka.Text, cmbPaino.Text, cmbKaytto.Text, cmbRotu.Text, cmbSukupuoli.Text, cmbKunto.Text, cmbRehunkayttokyky.Text, int.Parse(vanhat[0]), vanhat[1], vanhat[2],vanhat[3], vanhat[4], vanhat[5], vanhat[6], vanhat[7], vanhat[8]);
        this.hevosetBindingSource.EndEdit();
        hevosetTableAdapter.Update(this.dsHevonen.Hevoset);
        hevosetTableAdapter.Connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
    }    
    hevosetTableAdapter.Connection.Close();
}
```

`lueVanhatTiedot()` function gets the original data for the record.
Still learning to program so there may be stupid mistakes which I just can't notice. :)

Comment: What's the purpose of "hevosetTableAdapter.Update(txtNimi.Text, txtIka.Text, cmbPaino.Text, cmbKaytto.Text, cmbRotu.Text, cmbSukupuoli.Text, cmbKunto.Text, cmbRehunkayttokyky.Text, int.Parse(vanhat[0]), vanhat[1], vanhat[2],vanhat[3], vanhat[4], vanhat[5], vanhat[6], vanhat[7], vanhat[8]);" ?

Comment: The first parameters are the new values and the vanhat[x] are the old values. vanhat[0] is the key of the old record.
[Website to MSDN documentation for TableAdapter.Update command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233819.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Have you called the "AcceptChanges" method on the DataSet?

Comment: Tried that but it says "No overload method to Fill takes 17 arguments". The parameter should be a datatable. I also tried adding

        this.hevosetTableAdapter.Fill(this.dsHevonen.Hevoset);

before the update commands but then it changes the row I want to the same as the first row in the database.

Comment: Added it now, but it didn't help.
                hevosetTableAdapter.Update(this.dsHevonen.Hevoset);
                this.dsHevonen.Hevoset.AcceptChanges();

Comment: Uhm, strange behaviour. I found this content, hope can be helpfully: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bz9tthwx(v=vs.90).aspx